Twincat 2 ScopeView 2 export csv file
I using twincat 2 scope view 2 to record the data.  I have 2 channel in the Axis. First channel is store temperature, second channel is store the heater percentage. When I export the record to csv file, it only have one column of data. It separate the record using .  Eg: 028.800, 1028.8100, 1038.8200.  What is the value meaning?  And where is the temeprature value and the heater value? Below is the screen capture of the csv file.  Any setting I should configure?


Did you open the file or did you import it to excel? Seems like you opened it and it is treating commas as thousands seperator. The values you are seeing are most likely sample (0,1,2 ...) followed by the temperatre (28.8, 28.81, ...).
